# Combining If And Or functions into one in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'd like to build a formula that will state that if Cell C5 is equal to "Core Advocate" or "Advocate" or "Current Client" and if, at the same time, cell B5 is marked as "Yes," then the result needs to be "Text", otherwise the result is "No"

Answer (score 2):

[`AND()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301) and [`OR()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306) accept any number of arguments and return a Boolean value.

> **AND**
> Returns true if all of the provided arguments are logically true, and false if any of the provided arguments are logically false.
>
> **OR**
> Returns true if any of the provided arguments are logically true, and false if all of the provided arguments are logically false.

I think this will work:

```
=IF(AND(OR(C5="Core Advocate",C5="Advocate",C5="Current Client"),B5="Yes"),"Text","No")
```

Broken down for readability:

```
=IF(
  AND(
    OR(C5="Core Advocate",C5="Advocate",C5="Current Client")
    ,B5="Yes"
  )
  ,"Text","No"
)
```

Logic (from the inside, out):

```
OR(C5="Core Advocate",C5="Advocate",C5="Current Client")
```

will return *true* if any of the conditions are true.

```
AND(OR(...),B5="Yes")
```

will return *true* if the `OR()` and `B5="Yes"` are both true.

```
=IF(AND(OR(...)...),"Text","No")
```

Will display "Text" if the `AND()` returns true, "No" if it doesn't.